# How to reduce the spacing between the lines where there is a single long text in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a single TextView which has a string as shown in snapshot, How can I reduce the spacing between the lines.

**Snapshot**:
[image]

**Code**:

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_header"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="The swap request from KOMALJEET KAUR will time out in the next 3 hours, schedule pick up now."
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="-3dp"
                        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.5"
                        android:textColor="@color/clr_txt_header"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go in the right direction, lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier can help you achieve your goal. Note android:lineSpacingExtra="xdp" with x must greater than 1. lineSpacingMultiplier is a float like your usage. 
However, you can set it programmatically by `TextView.setLineSpacing()`

Comment: `txtDescription.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1.0f,  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 1.0f);` - This worked thanks :)